# is it possible to make parallax scrolling or smooth scrolling without jquery or javascript?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website using CSS and HTML only. When clicking a anchor link i wish it will go down to the id tag smoothly. Can I do that using only html and css?

i'm using only one html and it has a navigation bar upon clicking the link I want it to go down to a id tag where it was assigned to. I'm looking for a answer if this is possible? Can I do parallax scrolling without using jquery and javascript?

Comment: Well, actually you can. Check out these examples:
Animated scroll effect: http://jsfiddle.net/YYPKM/3/
Parallax image scrolling effect: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_parallax

Comment: For the record what you want is not what's called parallax. Parallax is a technique to animate items on screen simultaneously at different speed giving a 3D feeling